# How to create block diagram and analysis a simple RLC circuit in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, simulink, circuit, simscape

i have  [this](http://upload7.ir/imgs/2014-12/10196705397511655820.jpg)! RLC simple circuit

i want to analysis this circuit with different values of Resistance

but i dont know how can i draw a block diagram and simulink it with matlab, i just searched internet and found some libraries,but i didn't find anything special for my work, please if you have experience in this analysis help me and let me know how can i analysis it with MATLAB simulink

i think its very simple circuit , and if i found a way to create this in MATLAB , Matlab can analysis that easily, and i want to analysis this for different values of resistance , and i have constant L and C , for inductor and capacitor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're allowed and have access to it, the easiest way would be to use [Simscape](http://uk.mathworks.com/products/simscape/), which has an electrical library. See [Simulink Simscape simple circuit not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27252948/simulink-simscape-simple-circuit-not-working) for a similar question.